# "Failed to create Context 0x3005" for Android Emulator

Tags: android, eclipse, emulation

I installed a project in Eclipse and when I run Android emulator I get this error:

```
[2013-11-10 17:19:16 - Emulator] Failed to create Context 0x3005
[2013-11-10 17:19:16 - Emulator] emulator: WARNING: Could not initialize OpenglES emulation, using software renderer.
[2013-11-10 17:19:16 - Emulator] could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
[2013-11-10 17:19:16 - Emulator] could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
[2013-11-10 17:19:16 - Emulator] could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
[2013-11-10 17:19:16 - Emulator] could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
[2013-11-10 17:19:16 - Emulator] could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
[2013-11-10 17:19:16 - Emulator] could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
[2013-11-10 17:19:16 - Emulator] could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
[2013-11-10 17:19:16 - Emulator] could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
[2013-11-10 17:19:17 - MyNEWapp] New emulator found: emulator-5554
[2013-11-10 17:19:17 - MyNEWapp] Waiting for HOME ('android.process.acore') to be launched...
[2013-11-10 17:25:36 - MyNEWapp] HOME is up on device 'emulator-5554'
[2013-11-10 17:25:36 - MyNEWapp] Uploading MyNEWapp.apk onto device 'emulator-5554'
[2013-11-10 17:25:40 - MyNEWapp] Installing MyNEWapp.apk...
[2013-11-10 17:27:52 - MyNEWapp] Failed to install MyNEWapp.apk on device 'emulator-5554!
[2013-11-10 17:27:52 - MyNEWapp] (null)
[2013-11-10 17:27:53 - MyNEWapp] Launch canceled!
```

Can you help me to resolve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I've had this problem once. This is how I solved it:

1. Open AVD Manager
2. Select your emulator
3. Click on edit
4. Check - Use Host GPU

Comment: Hi. I have already active "Use Host GPU". Comes the same error.

Comment: Hello again. A quick Google search gave me [this link](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=41032). It seems to be an unsolved issue, in some cases.

Answer (score 0):

If the above solution does not work it means there are no drivers for your graphics card .
I had exactly the same problem.
 **The solution was quite simple. Install the driver for my video card Gforce 9600GT.**

https://askubuntu.com/questions/172312/stuck-with-launching-new-emulator